# How to make a post request using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, http-post, swifty-json

I have been following this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/parse-json-with-swift/
And have followed every instructions as it is. But i just coulddn't make the http post request work as it seems like my api service can't get the requested parameter. So this is my httppost request method:

```
private func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, body: [String: AnyObject], onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

        // Set the method to POST
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        do {
            // Set the POST body for the request
            let jsonBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: .PrettyPrinted)

            request.HTTPBody = jsonBody
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
                if let jsonData = data {
                    let json:JSON = JSON(data: jsonData)

                    onCompletion(json, nil)

                } else {

                    onCompletion(nil, error)
                }

            })
            task.resume()

        } catch {
            // Create your personal error
            onCompletion(nil, nil)
        }
    }
```

then i have created a function to call it:

```
func registerNewUser(email: String,url: String, onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {

        let route = baseURL + url

        print(route)

        let postItems:[String: String] = ["email": email]
        print("postitems",postItems)



        makeHTTPPostRequest(route, body: postItems, onCompletion: { json, err in

            onCompletion(json as JSON)

            print("response",json)

        })

    }
```

Then calling it from signup controller:

```
func requestSignUp()
    {
        if((emailField.text?.isEmpty) == false)
        {
        //performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerification", sender: signUpBtn)

            let url = "user/signup"
            RestApiManager.sharedInstance.registerNewUser(emailField.text! as String, url: url as String,  onCompletion: {
                (json: JSON) in if let results = json[0].array {
                    for entry in results {

                        print(entry)

                    }
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

the print shows the format of the postitems under register user as :

**postitems ["email": "dasdsd"]**

And my service response shows this:

```
response {
  "responseData" : {

  },
  "responseStat" : {
    "status" : false,
    "isLogin" : false,
    "requestError" : [

    ],
    "msg" : "The email field is required.",
    "extra" : {

    }
  }
}
```

the email field parameter is **email** and on successful submission it would show something like this:

```
{
  "responseStat": {
    "status": true,
    "isLogin": false,
    "msg": "Successfully Registered an, your password has been sent to your email",
    "requestError": [],
    "extra": {}
  },
  "responseData": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding this line in my **makeHTTPPostRequest** made it working:

```
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) alongside [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) with Ease:

```
static func requestToSendObject(value: YOUROBJECT) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://google.com")!
    let params: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "object_key" : value
    ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        if let data = response.result.value {
            let responseJSON = JSON(data)
            // Use the responseJSON
        }
    }
}
```